In a Python debugger how would I be able to setting a return value in a return event?
In the debugger that I have been developing trepan3k, I would when stopped at a "return" event, I'd like the ability for the user to be able to change the return value that the caller sees. Can that be done without having the user run a modified Python?
Some background. Recall that at one sys.settrace() event is a "return" event and the callback hook gives as an argument to this callback the value will be returned to the calling function.
Inside the debugger, I would like to allow the user to be able to change this value. Of course, one can change the Python interpreter, but this is a bit drastic.
Compiling an extension in C would be okay - the feature then would be optional.
